# How do I bind a specific symbol sequence to produce different sequence?

Tags: xubuntu, shortcut-keys, xfce

I am wondering if there's any way (via XFCE DE) to produce something like the following (which is available at Mac OS), you type :sequence: and something else is produced, like that:

[image]

Comment: Can you please be more specific? What software are you thinking of? Xfce is a whole collection of applications.